# Lambda API returned error: Network Connection. Unable to connect to endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora

We're getting that error when trying to execute the following instruction:

```
CALL mysql.lambda_async ('LAMBDA_ARN','{"operation": "ping"}')
```

Our Aurora MySQL instance is behind a private VPC, but I can see a NAT Gateway attached to the VPC. So even though we've followed the instructions laid out [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.Network.html).

It is still not working.

We can't even get it to work with VPC endpoints created to S3 or SNS....

Our Aurora version is:

2.04.5

We expect to be able to call lambda from Aurora...

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting? Did you also follow the guide to give Aurora access to Lambda? https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html#AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LambdaAccess

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and there were a lot of little pieces I needed to get right to make everything work.  You probably need to make a route table that passes 0.0.0.0/0 to the NAT Gateway instead of the internet gateway.  If you're using a bastion to get into your RDS, and it's on the same subnets as the RDS, this will break the bastion being able to connect to the internet.  What I did is made 3 new subnets, a new subnet group (of the 3 new subnets), a new route table (pointing 0.0.0.0/0 to the NAT Gateway), and remade the DB using that new subnet group.  As long as the security groups are still set up right, your bastion should have no problem connecting to the new RDS instance on a different subnet.